# SQL Server - 1 to 1 relationship best practice

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration

I have a table called Station with many fields,
one of the fields is - StationPrice.

I want to hold more information about the payment process such as - currency, paymentStatus and etc (somewhere like 10 fields).
My question is if I need to expand the current table - Station with the new fields or to have a field called - StationPriceId that will be a foreign key to another table called StationPrices which will store all the information about the price related to that station.

Comment: `mysql` isn't `sql-server`. i've removed the irrelevant tag for you.

Comment: please provide what you have done before? share your query or code.

Comment: Its not a query/code question, more about architecture.
I dont know if holding more information about the price in the same table - Station is the best thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is 1 of the most popular answers in DB world - **it depends**. It might look nicer if this info is split into 2 different tables, however you need to understand that if you split it then you'll need to 2 inserts instead of 1, the same with updated and deletes. Moreover you'll need to JOIN this table every time you'll need this data. I would go with single table first and then moved it to the separate column when the specific need come up.

From other side of view, if this data will be rarely accessed and JOIN/DELETE/INSERT overhead will be minimal then it is OK to move it.

Comment: DELETE/UPDATE can be done easily with cascade, also insert can be done with trigger, my only concern is if I need to update information that is price specific why will I want to get all the information about the Station?

Comment: You can add CASCADE, also add a trigger, but what benefit will you have? You add complexity to the project and it will hurt one day.

Comment: its kinda tricky, because my benefits will be that now I hold another table with all the information related to the price and I can update this table specifically instead of get the Station table, but again it will required then to worry about something else - the inserts, deletion and all this

Comment: I do agree that it adds complexity, thats why I posted this question, because I dont know what will be best for future use

Comment: as I said already - it depends. Nobody will give you an answer that will work in 100% cases. As I said that I would move it to another table if only it is very rarely used in queries.

Comment: a true one-to-one relationship is rarely used since this relationship has no actual benefit. One case could be if you have millions of records in table Station but only a few have the price fields filled. In that case you could save a few bytes by storing them seperate. But otherwise I can not think of any reason to create a one-to-one relationship like this

Comment: @GuidoG creating/rebuilding indexes can be affected

Comment: that is also true for the seperate table

Comment: @GuidoG sure, but 1 thing is to rebuild million row table with some values and another one is to rebuild one with much fewer rows. For example if the price of station changed, the FK will not and there is no need to rebuild main table.

Comment: if there is no index on the pricecolumn than there is no need to rebuild the main table either, or am i wrong about this ?

Comment: In the rules of normalization there is no reason to create a sepearate table for this. But as mentioned before it can still be done for some reasons. Without knowing more details its hard to answer this

Answer (score 0):

`My question is if I need to expand the current table - Station with the new fields or to have a field called - StationPriceId that will be a foreign key to another table called StationPrices which will store all the information about the price related to that station.`

Yes it is better to use two tables, Based on information you had provided - it is better to use a separate table.

1. You might want to maintain a price change history
2. Hence if you maintain a separate table, you can make earlier price as Active = false and enter a new price for the particular station